# How do I get a list of the fullpaths of every .git subfolder in a directory tree?

Tags: ls, dir

I am unable to figure out the right set of commands in a Windows Command prompt FOR /? or bash ls to do this.

The following batch file I wrote demonstrates what I want, but I would like to know if there's a way to do it without a batch file.

```
@echo off
for /r %%i in (.) do if %%~nxi==.git echo %%i
```

Seems like I should be able to issue a DIR command with a combination of /s /b and /ad to do this.  I'm willing to filter through grep or FIND if I need to.

I obviously don't need a solution that require a script since I already have that as demonstrated above.

Also, Powershell may be a candidate as long as it's a simple command.

Comment: Replace `%%` with `%` to use the command line: `for /r %i in (.) do if %~nxi==.git echo %i`

Comment: That won't work.  If you have 1000s of files and directories, you will see 1000s of lines scroll by, and you'll hardly see the one where it echo's out.   You'd have to echo >> to some file and the 'type' that file out.   Seems painful.

Comment: {shrug} You can tweak that command to only echo the stuff you want (using `@`) and pipe `|` the output to `more`

Comment: David, I did try the "@" trick before I posted this question.  It didn't work.   I did not try the pipe more trick.   I'll try that and let you know.

Comment: It worked.   I put the `@` on the `if` not on the `for`.   So the line looks like this: `for /r %i in (.) do @if %~nxi==.git echo %i`.   Can you please create an answer with your suggestion so I can accept it?

Comment: Done. Answer provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The following batch file I wrote demonstrates what I want

> but I would like to know if there's a way to do it without a batch file.
>
> ```
> @echo off
> for /r %%i in (.) do if %%~nxi==.git echo %%i
> ```

You can do this from the command line by making the following changes:

1. Replace `%%` with `%`
2. Replace `if` with `@`if` to remove superfluous output

So the command becomes:

```
for /r %i in (.) do @if %~nxi==.git echo %i
```

If the output is more than one screenfull you can either:

- Pipe the output to `more`

  ```
  for /r %i in (.) do @if %~nxi==.git echo %i | more
  ```

Or:

- Redirect the output to a file and examine it later.

  ```
  for /r %i in (.) do @if %~nxi==.git echo %i > output.txt
  more output.txt
  ```

---

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [echo](http://ss64.com/nt/echo.html) - Display messages on screen, turn command-echoing on or off.
- [for /r](http://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html) - Loop through files (Recurse subfolders).
- [more](https://ss64.com/nt/more.html) - Display output one screen at a time. MORE can be used to run any executable command (or batch file) and pause the screen output one screen at a time.
- [parameters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) - A command line argument (or parameter) is any value passed into a batch script.
- [redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) - Redirection operators.